# PHP Socket read crypted message

Tags: php, sockets, cryptography

I have a server socket in PHP and javascript client, the connection is fine, the problem comes from the client when I try to send a message to the server:

```
socket.send(msg + '\n');
```

Obviamente [B]msg [/B]es una cadena de texto que ya comprobé que está bien, un simple 'hola', por ejemplo.

On the server performed the procedure for reading this post:

```
$bytes = @socket_recv($socket, $buffer, 2048, MSG_WAITALL);

if ( $bytes == 0 ) {
    disconnect($socket);
} else {
    echo $buffer;
}
```

And with the 'echo' chains are printed like this:
    **„Ž.°*ï]Ô**

Also, if you repeatedly send the same string in 'msg', always get a different encrypted string.

I have looked at several sites and apparently the chains should arrive normally, do not understand why this happens. Another thing, I am not relying in: https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/

Regards.

Comment: HTML5 WebSockets are not raw socket connections.  You need to implement the WebSocket protocol.

Comment: Please see this article: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/